# Php to take the js variable and passed as a parameter

Tags: javascript, php

I would like to call js variable in php as a parameter passed to php function.What method should I use to take the sj value

```js
<script type='text/javascript'>
var js_test = '132';
<?php
   $test = function($parameter); //The value of the parameter is expected to be a variable of js above
   echo $test;
?>
</script>
```

Comment: Read about Jquery ajax

Comment: I know use ajax, but want to execute directly on the client side

Comment: you can't run the `php code` in `client side` . because it's `server side scripting language` .

Comment: When javascript code is running, there is no php script to handle js variables, because PHP runs on server and js runs on client machine

Comment: think you，I know their difference, sometimes the code is written for a long time, just like a simple solution to the problem

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use JS to send the URL back with a variable in it such as: http://www.example.com/index.php?uid=1
by using something like this in JS:

window.location.href=”index.php?uid=1";
Then in the PHP code use $_GET:
$somevar = $_GET["uid"];

Comment: Use ajax to solve the problem, thank you very much for your reply

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry to say but there is no way to do exactly this without reloading the page or using AJAX.

The problem is that ALL PHP is processed before the HTML and Javascript is even loaded. It is not top-down processing of the entire page contents. ALL PHP is processed first by the server, everything else is completely ignored. So your js_test variable or any JS as a matter of fact will not even exist before your PHP function is called.

One way to do this is using a $_POST or $_GET to the page. See this working example:

```
<?php
function callFunction($val)
{
    echo "Function called and it is ".$val;
}

if(isset($_GET['js_test']))
{
    callFunction($_GET['js_test']);
} else {
?>
<script type='text/javascript'>
var js_test = '132';
if (typeof js_test != 'undefined' || js_test != '')
{
    window.location.href = '/phptest.php?js_test='+js_test;
}
</script>
<?php
}
?>
```

That of course requires a reload of the page.

The other way to do this is to use an AJAX call to a separate PHP file which has the PHP function, which will then echo the result back to your main page after processing it.

Comment: Intended to direct call, simple and easy, I was trying for a long time, it seems not feasible, I will use ajax deal, very grateful

Comment: The JS for your convenience:
`var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            var returnedvalue = this.responseText;
           //do what you want with returnedvalue
}
};
xhttp.open("GET", "phptest.php?js_test="+js_test, true);
xhttp.send();`

Comment: or if you are using JQuery:
 `$.ajax({
 url: "phptest.php",
 data: {js_test:js_test},
 method:"POST",
 success: success
 });
 function success( returnedval ) {
       //do what you want with returnedval
       }
});`

Comment: Phase of the original ajax, I prefer `$ .ajax ({code})`, because more clear, but the original is also very good.

Comment: In order to be your answer more nice you can view the document, but your answer is very useful.  [web]: https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#html "document"

Comment: Oh okay, thank you, yeah I was wondering why it looks like that.

Answer (score 0):

The Best Approach Would Be An ajax call. The Only difference between ajax and this method is Reloading the page.In Ajax Call you can Prevent Page From refreshing.

You can   pass js variable through url method from js to php

```
 <script type='text/javascript'>
    var js_test = '132';
    ///Call this function in js whenever you want to send js Variable 

    function send(){
//Replace index.php with the path of your page
    window.location.href=”index.php?var="+js_test;
    }

    </script>
```

That Doesn't matter now Wherever you keep php code

here's the php code

```
<?php
// If Condition to set function work only if there is variable in Url
if(isset($_GET["var"])){
   $test = function($_GET["var"]);  //The value of the parameter is expected to be a variable of js above
   echo $test;
}
?>
```

if you Wish to do this with AJAX here is the js code for Ajax Call

```
<script>
 var js_test =132;
 var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
              alert(this.responseText);
//Do Whatever You want to do With Response text
            }
        };
        xmlhttp.open("GET", "function.php?var=" + json_test, true);
        xmlhttp.send();
</script>
```

Comment: Your answer is very exciting, the use of window.location will make the page jump, so the use of ajax asynchronous request more comfortable. think you vrey much

Comment: @silence here  is the JS for Ajax Call